# How to rewrite class component to React Functional?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am new to React and I am learning the basics, but right now I need to rewrite a Class component in order to use React Hooks. So I guess I need to rewrite it to a functional component.

I already tried changing some of the things but in the end everything breaks and I will get a 'props not defined' error.

This is the code:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let close = (
      <div
        className="close"
        onClick={() => {
          this.props.onCloseArticle()
        }}
      ></div>
    )

    return (
      <div
        ref={this.props.setWrapperRef}
        id="main"
        style={this.props.timeout ? { display: 'flex' } : { display: 'none' }}
      >
        <article
          id="vision"
          className={`${this.props.article === 'vision' ? 'active' : ''} ${
            this.props.articleTimeout ? 'timeout' : ''
          }`}
          style={{ display: 'none' }}
        >
          <h2 className="major">Vision</h2>
          <span className="image main">
            <img src={pic01} alt="" />
          </span>
          <p>
            Adipiscing magna sed dolor elit. Praesent eleifend dignissim arcu,
            at eleifend sapien imperdiet ac. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent
            urna nisi, fringila lorem et vehicula lacinia quam. Integer
            sollicitudin mauris nec lorem luctus ultrices.
          </p>
          <p>
            Nullam et orci eu lorem consequat tincidunt vivamus et sagittis
            libero. Mauris aliquet magna magna sed nunc rhoncus pharetra.
            Pellentesque condimentum sem. In efficitur ligula tate urna.
            Maecenas laoreet massa vel lacinia pellentesque lorem ipsum dolor.
            Nullam et orci eu lorem consequat tincidunt. Vivamus et sagittis
            libero. Mauris aliquet magna magna sed nunc rhoncus amet feugiat
            tempus.
          </p>
          {close}
        </article>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Main.propTypes = {
  route: PropTypes.object,
  article: PropTypes.string,
  articleTimeout: PropTypes.bool,
  onCloseArticle: PropTypes.func,
  timeout: PropTypes.bool,
  setWrapperRef: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default Main
```

What I did is changing `class main` to `const Main = () => {`, remove the `render()` but after that I am confused..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the work

1. Replace `class` by `const`
2. Remove the `render` lifecycle method used in class components
3. Add the `props` in the parameter of the function
4. Remove all the `this`

```
const Main = (props) => {
    let close = (
      <div
        className="close"
        onClick={() => {
          props.onCloseArticle()
        }}
      ></div>
    )

    return (
      <div
        ref={props.setWrapperRef}
        id="main"
        style={props.timeout ? { display: 'flex' } : { display: 'none' }}
      >
        <article
          id="vision"
          className={`${props.article === 'vision' ? 'active' : ''} ${
            props.articleTimeout ? 'timeout' : ''
          }`}
          style={{ display: 'none' }}
        >
          <h2 className="major">Vision</h2>
          <span className="image main">
            <img src={pic01} alt="" />
          </span>
          <p>
            Adipiscing magna sed dolor elit. Praesent eleifend dignissim arcu,
            at eleifend sapien imperdiet ac. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent
            urna nisi, fringila lorem et vehicula lacinia quam. Integer
            sollicitudin mauris nec lorem luctus ultrices.
          </p>
          <p>
            Nullam et orci eu lorem consequat tincidunt vivamus et sagittis
            libero. Mauris aliquet magna magna sed nunc rhoncus pharetra.
            Pellentesque condimentum sem. In efficitur ligula tate urna.
            Maecenas laoreet massa vel lacinia pellentesque lorem ipsum dolor.
            Nullam et orci eu lorem consequat tincidunt. Vivamus et sagittis
            libero. Mauris aliquet magna magna sed nunc rhoncus amet feugiat
            tempus.
          </p>
          {close}
        </article>
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Good, but you forgot to destruct props.